# MySQL: limit results by a calculated step interval

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a need to return a specific number of rows from a query within a given start and stop time at a dynamically calculated step interval.

I've kept it simple here with a table consisting of a unix timestamp and a corresponding integer value.

In my example, I need to have **200** rows returned with an INCLUSIVE start time of **1307455099** and and an INCLUSIVE end time of **1307462455**.

Here's the current query I've developed so far. It uses the modulus of the total rows to calculate the step interval:

```
SELECT timestamp, value FROM soh_data
WHERE timestamp % (CAST((1307462455 - 1307455099)/200 AS SIGNED INTEGER)) = 0
AND timestamp BETWEEN 1307455099 AND 1307462455 
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

The first problem is that because I'm using a modulus, the start and end times aren't always inclusive (that's solvable with an extra query... I'm fine with that).

The second, and more difficult issue to tackle, is that the total rows returned in this case is only 196.  In most queries, it's n-1.

FYI, this is on a MySQL database with millions of rows of data.

Any insights?

Comment: why are you using a modulus?  What are you trying to pull again... a random sampling between those 2 timestamps?

Comment: I'm trying to pull an evenly-spaced subset of per-second values within a range.  The modulus establishes the approximate step interval of the subset.  Since the timestamp/value pairs are collected once a second, I have a relatively predictable range set between lower and upper timestamps. I'm now considering pre-calculating the step interval (modulus) in code first now (C++).  That way, I zero in on it instead of estimating it in SQL (timestamp % (upper - lower)/limit)

Comment: Thank you for posting this. It is useful in the situation where you are batch processing large numbers of rows in parallel threads, but the data in the rows is "bunched up", such that the threads clash with each other when you simply use 'order by' + 'limit', and so you want your threads to process data selected from rows distributed across the entire set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm fine with throwing away a few rows, but I'm not alright with too little data, I've come up with two different approaches.

First: I've decided to adapt my query to use `FLOOR` instead of `CAST`.  In my example, the quotient of the division was 21.805. SQL rounded that up to 22.  The right step interval for gathering more than 200 results was 21 (yielding 205 results).  Using FLOOR will give me the step number of 21 I need.  Unfortunately, I haven't fully tested this to ensure consistent results across larger sets:

```
SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM soh_data 
WHERE timestamp % (FLOOR((1307459460 - 1307455099)/200)) = 0 
AND timestamp BETWEEN 1307455099 AND 1307459460 
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

---

The more reliable solution is to pre-calculate the step in code.  This way, I can zero in on the step programmatically. In the following example, I use Ruby for readability, but my ultimate solution will be coded in C++:

```
lower = 1307455099
upper = 1307459460

limit = 200
range = lower..upper
matches = 0
stepFactor = ((upper-1) - (lower+1))/limit

while (matches <= (limit - 2)) do
    matches = 0

    range.each { |ts| matches += 1 if (ts % stepFactor == 0) }

    stepFactor -= 1 # For the next attempt

    puts "Step factor = #{stepFactor+1}"
    puts "Matches = #{matches}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows returned would depend entirely on how many timestamps match your condition, of course. Let's say your step value comes out to 2, so your modulo math boils down to 'only even numbered timestamps'.  If by chance all items in your table have odd time stamps, then you're going to get 0 rows returned, even though there's (say) 500+ items within the time range.

If you need exactly 200, you'd probably be better off using `LIMIT` in some way.

Comment: Yes. I need exactly 200 rows.  The problem with using `LIMIT` is it's a hard cutoff, and I'd lose data at the upper or lower end depending on the `ORDER BY` clause.